# Error installing ipykernel (and others) in Conda environment due to QGIS Python installation

Tags: python, anaconda, qgis

I am trying to install the ipykernel package in a Conda environment so that I can use it with Jupyter Notebook, but I am running into an error related to my QGIS Python installation. QGIS is in my base, and I've seen other errors related to this. Specifically now, when I run the command python -m ipykernel install --user --name=myenv  I get the following error:

```
Error processing line 1 of /Users/grantmacdonald/opt/anaconda3/envs/icepyx/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib-3.7.1-py3.11-nspkg.pth:

Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen site>", line 186, in addpackage
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib.util>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib._abc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 982, in exec_module
  File "<frozen site>", line 616, in <module>
  File "<frozen site>", line 603, in main
  File "<frozen site>", line 384, in addsitepackages
  File "<frozen site>", line 226, in addsitedir
  File "<frozen site>", line 196, in addpackage
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/re.py", line 125, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: SRE module mismatch
(icepyx) grantmacdonald@Grants-MacBook-Pro ~ % jupyter notebook

Error processing line 1 of /Users/grantmacdonald/opt/anaconda3/envs/icepyx/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib-3.7.1-py3.11-nspkg.pth:

Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen site>", line 186, in addpackage
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib.util>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib._abc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 982, in exec_module
  File "<frozen site>", line 616, in <module>
  File "<frozen site>", line 603, in main
  File "<frozen site>", line 384, in addsitepackages
  File "<frozen site>", line 226, in addsitedir
  File "<frozen site>", line 196, in addpackage
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/tokenize.py", line 32, in <module>
    import re
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/re.py", line 125, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: SRE module mismatch
```